# Wordpress like plugins with custom CMS in nette

Tags: plugins, content-management-system, nette

We are developing CMS based in nette for our company and we have to design it to be plugin based for our clients. Something like wordpress but custom for our needs. Is there some easy way in nette to build system that will check updates and have some "plugin store" with automatic instalation without, so the user won't have to edit the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check how other CMS 'plugin based' systems deal with that and you probably find the answer (cause this is independent of nette or other frameworks). In general, you need to have some server that store plugins and same server can be used for plugin auto updates. Auto updating can be triggered with cron or after some user visit page (some action that is defined in CMS[some hook] trigger auto update of a plugin). Same principle can be used for updating core of the CMS or a theme.